# Deployment of 2 web applications(Having different host) in Tomcat 7 under one appbase

Tags: tomcat

I am using **Tomcat 7** as webserver and the **Apache** as the front end. I have below two applications which I want to deploy under **webapps** deployment folder of the tomcat.

- app1.war
- app2.war

Both the applications should be accessible using different hosts:

- www.dev.company.com (This is for app1.war and it should be accessible via both **http** and **https**)
- www.dev.test.company.com(This is for app2.war and should be accessible only via **https** and **http** should be re-directed to **https**)

What would be the standard and the best configuration which should be followed to deploy them?

Appreciated for quick answers.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Take a look at VirtualHosts in Apache to get started.

Comment: Thanks @clmarquart. I have created 2 virtual hosts in the server.xml. I have kept both the wars under webapps. For 1st host i.e. for app1.war, I have kept context and docbase is set to $(CATALINA.BASE)/webapps. For the 2nd host, I have kept appbase as webapps.This works except one thing is that the app2.war is still accessible via http. I am not sure if this is fine OR should I keep both the wars outside tomcat directory and provide context for both in server.xml under their host?